# How can I make only one choice available from 3?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I disable other spans when I click on the button to show one span as a pop up?

I want to make only one choice available but I don't know how to do it.
If I select one of the 3 options I don't want to be able to select another one, i want to make the other ones unavailable

I know it's kind of useless but I really need this for a project of mine, can anyone please help me with this?

```js
function junior() {
  var junior = document.getElementById("myjunior");
  junior.classList.toggle("show");
}

 function adult() {
  var adult = document.getElementById("myadult");
  adult.classList.toggle("show"); 
}

 function senior() {
  var senior = document.getElementById("mysenior");
  senior.classList.toggle("show"); 
}
```

```css
.junior  {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
   .adult {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
   .senior {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.junior .juniortext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}
  .adult .adulttext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}
  .senior .seniortext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}

.junior .juniortext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.adult .adulttext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.senior .seniortext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.junior .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}
 .adult .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}
 .senior .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;} 
  to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity:1 ;}
}
```

```html
<h1>&nbsp;</h1>  
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 33.3333%;"> 
<div class="junior" onclick="junior()">JUNIOR
  <span class="juniortext" id="myjunior" >A Simple junior Popup!</span>
</div>
  </td>
<td style="width: 33.3333%;"> 
<div class="adult" onclick="adult()" >ADULT
  <span class="adulttext" id="myadult" >A Simple adult Popup!</span>
</div>
  </td>
<td style="width: 33.3333%;"> 
<div class="senior" style="text-align: left;">
  <div class="senior" onclick="senior()" >SENIOR
  <span class="seniortext" id="mysenior" >A Simple senior Popup!</span>
</div>
  </div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I whant to be able to select any of the options, but just one at a time and if i select it i whant the other 2 to be unavailable until i refresh the page, then i cand select another one but just one, i dont know if it makes sense, im very bad at explaining things :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an extra variable to store the current element id,and if other button are click,we can check the id is the same or not,if not then prevent it from shown.

BTW: you had better use one function instead of 3 similar functions

```js
let clickedId = null
function clickTest(id) {
  if(clickedId){
    if(id!=clickedId){
      return null
    }else{
      clickedId = null
    }
  }else{
    clickedId = id
  }
  var senior = document.getElementById(id);
  senior.classList.toggle("show"); 
}
```

```css
.junior  {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
   .adult {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
   .senior {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.junior .juniortext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}
  .adult .adulttext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}
  .senior .seniortext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}

.junior .juniortext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.adult .adulttext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.senior .seniortext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.junior .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}
 .adult .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}
 .senior .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;} 
  to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity:1 ;}
}
```

```html
<h1>&nbsp;</h1>  
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 33.3333%;"> 
<div class="junior" onclick="clickTest('myjunior')">JUNIOR
  <span class="juniortext" id="myjunior" >A Simple junior Popup!</span>
</div>
  </td>
<td style="width: 33.3333%;"> 
<div class="adult" onclick="clickTest('myadult')" >ADULT
  <span class="adulttext" id="myadult" >A Simple adult Popup!</span>
</div>
  </td>
<td style="width: 33.3333%;"> 
<div class="senior" style="text-align: left;">
  <div class="senior" onclick="clickTest('mysenior')" >SENIOR
  <span class="seniortext" id="mysenior" >A Simple senior Popup!</span>
</div>
  </div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: how can i make it so that i can't unselect my choise? if i click again on the same text i don't want the popup to disappear

Comment: @GGalusca you need to check previous clicked id and current clicked it,if they are the same,then do not invoke `toggle`

Comment: I have no idea how to do this, Can you show me how to do it by editing the one above?
(ps: i'm so sorry for bothering you with this :D it's just a project for school and you are my biggest help, thank you very much <3)

Comment: @GGalusca I would suggest you to post a new question

Comment: i posted a new one, thanks!

Comment: @GGalusca I have added a new answer,if it's okay for you,do not forget to accpet and upvote it!